# How to enqueue scripts properly in admin widgets wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, select, woocommerce, widget

I have made custom widgets, I am enqueuing woocommerce scripts like selectWoo, wc-enhance, select2, its enqueuing in DOM, but not working, probably scripts loading before DOM. Can Anybody help me out?

```
if ( in_array( $screen_id, array( 'widgets' ) ) ) {
wp_enqueue_script( 'select2' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'selectWoo' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-enhanced-select' );

}
```